# Exctract one record from duplicates values

Tags: qgis, expression, qgsexpression

I'd like to exctract only one record from duplicates records (for example in a field "test") using "exctract by expression" in qgis.
Some records could be not duplicates, and obviously i have to exctract also these.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You tried with the expression `count ("test", "test")> 1` ?, extract all duplicate records

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select/extract all features with no duplicates and on duplicates only the first duplicate (by attribute only), you can use such an expression:

```
if($id = array_agg($id,"your_field")[0],true,false)
```

To select/extract only the first duplicate, and no features with no duplicates, you need to extend the expression:

```
if(count("your_field","your_field")>1 and $id = array_agg($id,"your_field")[0],true,false)
```

In addition you may want to take a look at the answers to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383287/eliminating-duplicates-only-if-data-is-the-same-according-to-attributes), to find **possible** duplicates.

Comment: also selects non-duplicate records

Comment: double check is needed:
`if(count("test","test")>1 and $id = array_agg($id,"test")[0],true,false)`

Comment: if my interpretation seems correct to you, modify your answer, for me it is ok